# When does $Ax=0$ have non zero solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Let $k > n$. Let $A$ be an $n\times k$ real matrix. I am interested in the non-zero solutions of the system of $Ax=0$. More precisely, I am looking for the most general conditions that $A$ must satisfy such that the system $Ax=0$ admits non zero solutions. Any idea ?

Comment: Non-zero solutions always exist under these conditions. There are multiple ways of explaining why that is, depending on your background. Do you know the rank-nullity theorem? Or do you know about the row echelon form?

Comment: The best classification whether $Ax=b$ has no solution, a unique solution or infinite many solutions is by determining the rank of $A$ and the rank of $A$ concatenated with $b$. The solution is unique, if both ranks coincide and are equal to the number of columns ($k$). But the maximum possible rank is $n$, which is smaller than $k$. Hence, the solution cannot be unique.

Answer (score 1):

let $A_1,A_2,...,A_k$ be column vectors of $A$ and $x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\x_k \end{pmatrix}$

$Ax=A\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\x_k \end{pmatrix}=x_1A_1+x_2A_2+...+x_kA_k=0$

$k>n \Rightarrow RankA \leq n$

$RankA \leq n <k \Rightarrow $ $\exists A_i:A_i=c_1A_1+...+c_{k-1}A_k$

$A_i=c_1A_1+...+c_{k-1}A_k \Rightarrow x_1A_1+...+x_iA_i+x_kA_k=(x_1+c_1x_i)A_1+...+(x_k+c_{k-1}x_i)A_k=0$

note that $x_i=1$ and $x_a=-c_a$ for all $i \neq a$ is a non-zero solution if $A_i\neq 0$

if $ A_i=0 $ then $x_1=...=x_k=0\neq x_i $ and $x_i=1$ is a non zero solution for equation

so $k > n$ is most general condition that $A$ has a non zero solution

Answer (score 0):

Nevzat's solution is kinda complicated.

As suggested by Thorgott:

1. We have $Rank(A)\leq\min\{n,k\}=n$ and by Rank-nullity theorem
   $$\small Rank(A)+Null(A)=\text{#columns}=k.$$
   It follows that
   $\small Null(A)=k-Rank(A)\geq k-n>0.$
2. Let $r$ be the number of pivots (or leader 1s) in the reduced row-echolon form of $A$. Clearly, $r\leq n$. Let $t$ be the number of parameters in the solution of the homogenous system $AX=0.$ Then
   $$r+t=\text{#variables}=k.$$
   It follows that $t=k-r\geq k-n>0.$